# Process substitution broken by a pipe

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection, command-substitution

I did a silly thing today:

```
read x <( ps -fu $LOGNAME | grep ' /usr/bin/ps$' )
```

It hung, never returned. I had to break it.

Some of you are quite rightly laughing at me right now. :)

It only took me a minute to see why this doesn't work, but I wanted to post it as a question (which I will briefly answer below as well, but feel free) in case it stumped someone.

Comment: "quite rightly laughing at me right now" XD

Comment: My own answer, which worked, was wrongly explained. I got an upvote and a downvote - I deleted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you replace `read x` with `cat`, how long does it take to run?

The problem is that you executed a command like:

```
read x /dev/fd/63
```

(as you could see by running `echo read x <(…)`)
and the `read` sat there waiting for you to type something for it to put in `x`.

```
$ read x <( ps -fu $LOGNAME | grep ' /usr/bin/ps$' )
asc def
-bash: read: `/dev/fd/63': not a valid identifier
$
```

The shell was waiting for you to type something, that's all.  You got impatient.

If you want to redirect the input to the `read` commnd, you need a separate `<` to do that (I needed to change the `grep` regex to get any output):

```
$ read x < <( ps -fu $LOGNAME | grep ' /usr/bin/ps' )
$ echo $x
501 16166 16164 0 7:50AM ttys000 0:00.00 grep /usr/bin/ps
$
```

Note that with the direct redirection as shown in the last `read` command, only the first line of input from the process substitution will be read; the rest will be lost.  If you need to process multiple lines in a `while` loop, you need to redirect the whole loop:

```
while read x
do
    whatever -with "$x"
done < <(ps -fu $LOGNAME | grep ' /usr/bin/ps')
```

See also the Bash manual on [Process Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution), where it says:

> Process substitution allows a process’s input or output to be referred to using a filename.

The result is a file name (on a Mac at least, it takes the form `/dev/fd/xx` for some numeric value of `xx`) that can be used to reference the output from the commands in the process substitution.